# Problem in the chat php/ajax(jquery)

Tags: php, ajax, chat

I programmed Chat script using PHP and jQuery but the problem is Will be great pressure on the server ??

If there is an answer please tell me

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the logic you've used.

If you make the server block for a sensible amount of time before sending a 'no data' response, load will be much less than if you fire off a new request every time you get a response from the server